# ObservableCollection as DependencyProperty - how to add / remove items in CollectionChanged event?

Tags: wpf

I have the following code:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ItemsSource", typeof (ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel>),
typeof (MultiSelectComboBoxUserControl),
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnItemsSourceChanged));

public static ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel> GetItemsSource(DependencyObject obj)
{
   return (ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel>) obj.GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
}

public static void SetItemsSource(DependencyObject obj, ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel> value)
{
   obj.SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
}

private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.OldValue != null)
     {
            var coll = (INotifyCollectionChanged) e.OldValue;
            coll.CollectionChanged -= ItemsSource_CollectionChanged;
     }

     if (e.NewValue != null)
     {
            var coll = (ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel>) e.NewValue;

            coll.CollectionChanged += ItemsSource_CollectionChanged;
     }
 }

 private static void ItemsSource_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
      //Here I'd like to update my ObservableCollection - ItemsSource
 }
```

How can I achieve this (updating ItemsSource)? I can't access it because it's a dependency property and event handler is a static method. Any tips very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The object that you receive as the `sender` parameter is the `ObservableCollection`. If you plan on changing the collection (such as adding or removing items) you may also need to detach the event handler before making changes.

```
private static void ItemsSource_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ObservableCollection collection = sender as ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel>;
    if (collection != null)
    {
        collection.CollectionChanged -= ItemsSource_CollectionChanged;

        //Update ObservableCollection

        collection.CollectionChanged += ItemsSource_CollectionChanged;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't change my ItemsSource instance at all. I would simply create my ObservableCollection instance and clear, add items when updating.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it simple!

Old code:

```
private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgse)
{
 if (e.OldValue != null)
 {
        var coll = (INotifyCollectionChanged) e.OldValue;
        coll.CollectionChanged -= ItemsSource_CollectionChanged;
 }

 if (e.NewValue != null)
 {
        var coll = (ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel>) e.NewValue;

        coll.CollectionChanged += ItemsSource_CollectionChanged;
 }
}
```

New Code:

```
private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgse)
{
 (YouCustomControl) control = (YouCustomControl)d;
 if (e.OldValue != null)
 {
        var coll = (INotifyCollectionChanged) e.OldValue;
        coll.CollectionChanged -= control.ItemsSource_CollectionChanged;
 }

 if (e.NewValue != null)
 {
        var coll = (ObservableCollection<BaseViewModel>) e.NewValue;

        coll.CollectionChanged += control.ItemsSource_CollectionChanged;
 }
}

private void ItemsSource_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
}
```